# How to see if a function is already registered to an event on an OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers-2, events

I am creating a data editing map using OpenLayers. I have two main states that the map editor can be in - editing existing features, or adding new ones. When a user clicks the "Edit Features" button, the `editOnClick` event is registered to the map. When the user clicks the "Add Feature" button, the `drawFeatureOnClick` event is registered to the map. I want to include a simple `if` statement to prevent OpenLayers from registering the same event multiple times, as well as remove the other button's event if it is active. Here's some pseudocode for the edit button:

```
$("#editfeatures").button({text: "Edit Features"}).click(function() {
    if (<editOnClick not already registered>) {
        map.events.register("click", map, editOnClick);
    }
    if (<drawFeatureOnClick currently registered>) {
        map.events.unregister("click", map, drawFeatureOnClick);
    }
}
```

I tried inspecting the map object using the Chrome debug tools, but I couldn't find an obvious way to tell if an event is currently registered on the map. **How can I see what event listeners are registered on the map?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem with a simple function:

```
function isEventRegistered(eventType, object, func) {
    var registered = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < object.events.listeners[eventType].length; i++) {
        eventObj = object.events.listeners[eventType][i];
        if (eventObj.func === func) {
            registered = true;
        }
    }
    return registered;
}
```

So now my edit button is this:

```
$("#editfeatures").button({text: "Edit Features"}).click(function() {
    if (!isEventRegistered('click', map, editOnClick)) {
        map.events.register('click', map, editOnClick);
    }
    if (isEventRegistered('click', map, drawFeatureOnClick)) {
        map.events.unregister('click', map, drawFeatureOnClick);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Tanner. Very good answer! :) Please, allow me to suggest something. You only test the ´func´. Shouldn't you include a 4th parameter for the scope of the callback and test it too? I might be wrong but I think that the OpenLayers.Event is entirely defined by these 3: ´eventType´, ´obj´ (scope of func) and ´func´. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

As an example, go to http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html

Type in your console `map.events.listeners` to get a list of registered events classified by events types.

To see if you really added your event to the map, just count the type of events you registered.

A sample could be

```
console.log('Before adding a new click event', map.events.listeners.click.length);

function test() {
  console.log('ok');
}

map.events.register("click", map, test);

console.log('After adding a new click event', map.events.listeners.click.length);
```

You will the number go from 9 to 10 registered click events on the map

Comment: Thanks for this. This didn't quite solve my problem of needing to check the existence of a specific function registered to a specific event, but it helped get me on the right track.